# Directory not rendering images because of cgi

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cgi, server

My server doesn't render any images under the cgi directory, I know that this is because apache is told to run every file under that directory as a cgi program.

I would like to adjust the settings to tell apache to run all the .cgi and .pl as cgi programs but run the rest of files as they should be.

For instance, if I go to `example.com/x.gif` from a browser I can see the image, but if I go to `example.com/cgi-bin/x.gif` I can't. (being the image in both dirs, of course, and with 775)

The problem is that I don't know how to tell that to apache, this is the httpd.include

> ```
> <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs>   
> <IfModule mod_perl.c>
> <Files ~ (\.pl$)>
>     SetHandler perl-script
>     PerlHandler ModPerl::Registry
>     Options ExecCGI
>     allow from all
>     PerlSendHeader On
> </Files> </IfModule> <IfModule mod_python.c>
> <Files ~ (\.py$)>
>     SetHandler python-program
>     PythonHandler mod_python.cgihandler
> </Files> </IfModule> <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
> <Files ~ (\.fcgi)>
>     SetHandler fcgid-script
>     Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
> </Files> </IfModule> <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
> <Files ~ (\.php)>
>     SetHandler fcgid-script
>     FCGIWrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper .php
>     Options +ExecCGI
>     allow from all
> </Files> </IfModule>
>
>     SSLRequireSSL
>
>     Options -Includes +ExecCGI
>
> </Directory>
> ```

Comment: Don't put images in there! It's called `cgi-bin` because it's for CGI binaries/executables - not images.

Comment: I really agree with you, but this is a server migration, and the original server worked this way. I can't change all the code (big project) for this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

As I said, apache is told to run every file under that directory as a cgi program. So are needed new rules to tell apache to use a default handler for those filetypes different from `.php` , `.pl` or `.cgi`:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/cgi-bin>   
<FilesMatch "^(?!.*\.(cgi|php|pl)$).*$">
    SetHandler default-handler
</FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

If you can't access the `httpd.conf` for any reason you still can do the trick with `.htaccess` adding this three lines to the `.htaccess` file of the `cgi-bin` folder:

```
<FilesMatch "^(?!.*\.(cgi|php|pl)$).*$">
    SetHandler default-handler
</FilesMatch>
```